# What is the reason for this error in ModelSim for my Verilog code? (string_literal.v(3): near ";": Syntax error.)

Tags: string, verilog, modelsim

```
module string_l();

string a;

initial
begin
a="Hello";
$display ("@%gns a=%s", $time, a);
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a `string` is a SystemVerilog datatype and you compiled with a Verilog `.v` file extension. Change the file extension to `.sv`.